# JavaScript canvas style left not being set in code

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to dynamically adjust the `left` position of a canvas. Width and height are fine to change, I know `left` requires CSS from some quick web searches. So here's what I've got:

HTML:
`<canvas id="output2" class="camera-canvas2"></canvas>`

CSS:

```
.camera-canvas2 {
            position: absolute;
            transform: scale(1, 1);
            transform-origin: 0 0;
            left: 510px;
            top: 10px;
        }
```

Javascript:

```
var canvas2 = document.getElementById('output2');

// Need to adjust right (canvas2) position
    let newOffset = Math.round(510-rightVideoOffset);
    let styleString = '"'+String(newOffset)+'px"'; //"510px" is default
    canvas2.style.left = styleString
    console.log("canvas2.style.left: "+String(canvas2.style.left)+" // "+styleString);
```

I have a button which toggles `rightVideoOffset` value, and that works fine for another feature that uses that variable. However examining the log, this `style.left` doesn't seem to do anything (console log below):

```
canvas2.style.left:  // "420px"
```

Visually, nothing happens. And in the log above, it should print the variable value of style.left, but it's blank when I try and inspect it.

How can I fix this and dynamically with JS shift the canvas position left?

Comment: where is rightVideoOffset defined? It is not shown in the code, could you perhaps give its value if it's no the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Padding" the styleString with quotation marks doesn't help it register as a string. Rather, it justs adds quotation marks to the end of the string. Rather than creating a string with `510px` as intended, this creates a string with the content `"510px"`, which is invalid input for CSS, so Javascript just ignores it without doing anything.

Instead, you should write something like `let styleString = newOffset + "px"`. Javascript will do the string-converting for you.

Example:

```js
var block = document.getElementById("block");
var otherBlock = document.getElementById("otherBlock");
function testNoWork() {
    let styleString = '"' + String(block.offsetLeft+20) + 'px"'
    block.style.left = styleString;
}
function testWorks() {
    let styleString = (otherBlock.offsetLeft+20) + 'px'
    otherBlock.style.left = styleString;
}
setInterval(testWorks, 1000);
setInterval(testNoWork, 1000);
```

```css
#block, #otherBlock {
    height: 1em;
    width: 1em;
    background-color: black;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0em;
    top: 0em;
}
```

```html
Doesn't work:
<div id="block" style="left:50px;top:50px;"></div>
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br />Works:
<div id="otherBlock" style="left:50px;top:150px;"></div>
```